# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split'). prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, prompt

Good afternoon,

Please, could you help me with an issue below.
I am getting an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')" when trying to click "cancel" on prompt.

What all I want, to loop canceled when I cancel it in prompt.

ps.: this is a simple array with a name/surname which in future will shows via console.log

```
function UserList () {
    let users = [];
    while(true) {
        users.push (prompt('Please, enter your name surname?').split(' '));
        if (prompt=== null) {
            alert('cancel');
        }
    }
}
let userList = new UserList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether the result of `prompt()` is `null` *before* you try to split it.

You need to break out of the loop when the user cancels, otherwise the function will never return.

Also, since you're using this as a object constructor, `users` should be a property `this.users`.

```
function UserList () {
    this.users = [];
    while(true) {
        let response = prompt('Please, enter your name surname?');
        if (response == null) {
            alert('cancel');
            break;
        }
        this.users.push (response.split(' '));
    }
}
```